# How to decode dictionary column when using pyarrow to read parquet files?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, parquet, pyarrow

I have three `.snappy.parquet` files stored in an s3 bucket, I tried to use `pandas.read_parquet()` but it only work when I specify one single parquet file, e.g: `df = pandas.read_parquet("s3://bucketname/xxx.snappy.parquet")`, but if I don't specify the filename `df = pandas.read_parquet("s3://bucketname")`, this won't work and it gave me error: `Seek before start of file`.

I did a lot of reading, then I found this [page](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28490#issuecomment-532884058)

it suggests that we can use `pyarrow` to read multiple parquet files, so here's what I tried:

```
import s3fs
import import pyarrow.parquet as pq
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
bucket_uri = f's3://bucketname'

data = pq.ParquetDataset(bucket_uri, filesystem=s3)
df = data.read().to_pandas()
```

This works, but I found that the value for one of the columns in thie `df` is a dictionary, how can I decode this dictionary and the selected `key` as column names and `value` as the corresponding values?

For example, the current column:

```
column_1
{'Id': 'xxxxx', 'name': 'xxxxx','age': 'xxxxx'....}
```

The expected column:

```
Id    age
xxx   xxx
xxx   xxx
```

Here's the output for `data.read().schema`:

```
column_0: string
  -- field metadata --
  PARQUET:field_id: '1'
column_1: struct<Id: string, name: string, age: string,.......>
  child 0, Id: string
    -- field metadata --
    PARQUET:field_id: '3'
  child 1, name: string
    -- field metadata --
    PARQUET:field_id: '7'
  child 2, age: string
    -- field metadata --
    PARQUET:field_id: '8'
  ...........
...........
```

Comment: Have you tried this `df['column_1'].apply(pd.Series)`

Comment: What does ` data.read().schema` return?

Comment: @0x26res Hi I've updated the example output for ` data.read().schema` in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a column with a "struct type" and you want to flatten it. To do so call [flatten](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.flatten) before calling `to_pandas`

```
import pyarrow as pa

COLUMN1_SCHEMA = pa.struct([('Id', pa.string()), ('Name', pa.string()), ('Age', pa.string())])
SCHEMA = pa.schema([("column1", COLUMN1_SCHEMA), ('column2', pa.int32())])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "column1": [("1", "foo", "16"), ("2", "bar", "17"), ],
    "column2": [1, 2],
})
pa.Table.from_pandas(df, SCHEMA).to_pandas() #  without flatten

| column1                                 |   column2 |
|:----------------------------------------|----------:|
| {'Id': '1', 'Name': 'foo', 'Age': '16'} |         1 |
| {'Id': '2', 'Name': 'bar', 'Age': '17'} |         2 |

pa.Table.from_pandas(df, SCHEMA).flatten().to_pandas() #  with flatten
|   column1.Id | column1.Name   |   column1.Age |   column2 |
|-------------:|:---------------|--------------:|----------:|
|            1 | foo            |            16 |         1 |
|            2 | bar            |            17 |         2 |
```

As a side note, you shoulnd't call it a `dictionary` column. `dictionary` is loaded term in pyarrow, and usually refer to [distionary encoding](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/data.html#dictionary-arrays)

**Edit: how to read a subset of columns in parquet**

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, SCHEMA)
pq.write_table(table, 'data.pq')
# Using read_table:
pq.read_table('data.pq', columns=['column1.Id', 'column1.Age'])
# Using ParquetDataSet:
pq.ParquetDataset('data.pq').read(columns=['column1.Id', 'column1.Age'])
```

Comment: what is `pa` you used in the code? `pyarrow`?

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now, and I got the flattened columns, just a follow-up question, after flatten the data, I only want part of the columns, is there a way to select them? I saw somewhere saying I can use `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset(bucket_uri, filesystem=s3,columns=selected_cols)`, but looks like this `columns` parameter is no long available.

Comment: When calling `ParquetDataset` you only load the metadata, not the data, so there's no need to select columns at that point. However you can select the columns when you call `read(columns=['column1.Id', 'column1.Age'])` which loads the actual data.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, what if I want to use `awswrangler.s3.read_parquet()`, it seems like it doesn't have a method similar to `.flatten()` here.

Comment: `awswrangler.s3.read_parquet()` returns a `Pandas DataFrame or a Generator in case of chunked=True.`. `flatten` only works on `pyarrow.Table`

Comment: Is there a way to flatten it when using `awswrangler.s3.read_parquet()`? I raised a separate question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68100249/how-to-decode-dictionary-column-when-using-awswrangler-to-read-parquet-files, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah actually I think this can be achieved with `pandas`, not necessary use `awswrangler`